# Confusing Error when Reading from a File in Python

Tags: python, file

I'm having a problem opening the `names.txt` file. I have checked that I am in the correct directory. Below is my code:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
def alpha_sort():
    infile = open('names', 'r')
    string = infile.read()
    string = string.replace('"','')
    name_list = string.split(',')
    name_list.sort()
    infile.close()
    return 0
alpha_sort()
```

And the error I got:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'names'

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You mention in your question body that the file is "names.txt", however your code shows you trying to open a file called "names" (without the ".txt" extension). (Extensions are part of  filenames.)

Try this instead:

```
infile = open('names.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, make sure that when you open files you use **universal** mode, as windows and mac/unix have different representations of carriage returns (/r/n vs /n etc.). Universal mode gets python to handle this, so it's generally a good idea to use it whenever you need to read a file. (EDIT - should read: a **text** file, thanks cameron)

So the code would just look like this

```
infile = open( 'names.txt', 'rU' ) #capital U indicated to open the file in universal mode
```

Comment: +1, but I just want to emphasize that this is for *text files only*.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve that issue, but you might consider using `with` when opening files:

```
with open('names', 'r') as infile:
    string = infile.read()
    string = string.replace('"','')
    name_list = string.split(',')
    name_list.sort()

return 0
```

This closes the file for you and handles exceptions as well.